# Unable to run docker-compose.yaml file on EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy a `docker-compose.yaml` on a public cloud VM. There is no other file I would like to deploy.

My file that contains 3 images to build the container (see code below): Kafka Broker, Zookeeper and Python-Producer (which basically just produces random numbers periodically and writes to a Kafka Topic; and this image is deployed publicly).

I have followed 2 comprehensive tutorials on how to deploy a container on VM using GCP & AWS EC2 meticulously. But I am getting the following errors

```
- On AWS EC2 on Linux → I am unable to install docker-compose engine
- On GCP VM on Ubuntu → I am able to run docker-compose up command but it throws an error stating the broker cannot be started
```

Link to AWS Deploy tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRgdnHHuvoI&t=142s

Link to GCP Deploy Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nt7fpz4JXzY

Any help and guidance will be much appreciated - TIA!